# Entity Framework Dynamically Add Type to Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic, reflection

In database there is a view and dynamically i am adding some columns in the select statement. And There is requirement that i have to add some new properties to existing class "Test" using reflection which i added to the sql view.

And i achieve this but the issue is how to query that table using linq. I tried with the code
but i am getting error

"Cannot create a DbSet for 'Test' because this type is not included in the model for the context."

Here is my code

```
var factory = new DynamicTypeFactory(typeof(Test));
            Type extendedType = factory.CreateNewTypeWithDynamicProperties(typeof(Test), new Dictionary<string, Type>
            {
            { "NewNote", typeof(string) },   { "NewLastModifiedDate", typeof(DateTime) },{ "NewStatus", typeof(string) }
            });
            var properties = extendedType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                         .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite);

            object extendedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(extendedType);

            
            var method = context.GetType().GetMethods().First(x => x.IsGenericMethod && x.Name == "Set");
            var genericSetMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(extendedType);
            ***var records = genericSetMethod.Invoke(context, null);***
```

So i the last line i am getting the error

The goal is using EF select the records from db.

Thanks

Comment: All the power of LINQ is shown in compile time. But you are doing something in runtime. In this case, LINQ is not your assistant, just give it up.